# Как перемешать в строке определенное количество символов в perl

Tags: perl, shuffle

От меня уже был подобный вопрос о перемешивание всех символов в строке, и мне умный человек на этом портале подсказал как это сделать, а именно через команду perl -MList::Util=shuffle -lnE 'say shuffle split("");'
Сейчас появилась необходимость изменить эту команду что бы считывалась строка и перемешивалась только часть строки. Например, есть текстовый фаил со строками, вроде 12345678901234567890, и мне необходимо что бы команда считывала всю строку, затем брала символы например с 10 по 16, и выводила готовую строку (например 12345678906435217890) в новый текстовый файл, а после переходила к обработке следующей. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, что надо сделать дополнительно, это разбить строку на части и в одной из этих частей перемешать символы.

В этом примере мы пропускаем первые 8 символов в строке, извлекаем следующие 8 символов, их перемешиваем и оставшуюся часть строки оставляем без изменений.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use v5.26.0;
use List::Util qw(shuffle);

open(my $fh, "<", $ARGV[0]) or die "Cant open: $!\n";
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    substr($_, 8, 8, join("", shuffle split("", substr($_, 8, 8))));
    say;
}
```

Для этого используем функцию `substr` с четырьмя аргументами. Подробнее о её работе можно почитать в `perldoc -f substr`.